# My program stay Frozen until answer

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I need help, well i´m connected through socket and when is connected my Spinner get frozen, it happens also when the socket is  off i need some help i will put my code, check and tell me wot is my problem please =)

[Files](http://www.mediafire.com/?4wozq1a47550n47)

Comment: Have you thought about posting the most important parts here? What have you already tried? Where do you think the error is?

Comment: Please post the pertinent sections of your code, instead of linking to your source.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're trying to do you socket communication stuff on the main UI thread. This is a major no-no in Android. You need to do your socket stuff on a different thread. For information on how to do with please read [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Using **[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** is a great way to do background tasks that don't block the UI.  Also, the callbacks for progress and completion are made on the UI thread so you don't have to manage thread affinity yourself.  I use this all the time to great effect.

Comment: Yes i try with AsyncTask but it didnt work =( the programm continue frozen when receive the answer =(

Comment: You're going to have to post code.  Unless there is some side-effect of opening a socket on android that i am unaware of, AysncTask should solve about 90% of the problems related to background tasks and keeping a responsive UI.  There are other classes like Handler and Runnable that can also help in situations where you need slightly more control.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options for handling long running tasks outside UI thread

1. Create your own thread
2. Use Async tasks
3. Use Dataloaders for Android 3.0 and above